# Как организовать пересылку данных по сокетам?

Tags: c, java, сокет, c++, сервер

Как организовать пересылку данных по сокетам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sockets programming in Java: A tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html)

> This tutorial presents an introduction to sockets programming over TCP/IP networks and shows how to write client/server applications in Java.